# powershell is giving different result while running in different server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

'get-wmiobject -class win32_share' is giving different result while running remotely from windows 2k12 R2 and locally from Windows 2k8 R2

I have a file server which is hosted on windows 2k8 R2. I am running the command(`get-wmiobject -class win32_share`) to generate the file shares locally and it is giving correct data.
But when I am running the command(`get-wmiobject -class win32_share -computername <<server_name>>`) from a windows 2012 R2 server, but it is giving more shares.

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_share

get-wmiobject -class win32_share -computername <<server_name>>
```

Comment: `<<server_name>>` in your example is the host name of the 2008R2 box?

Comment: Can you include the output of the command?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : yes you are correct

Comment: @HAL9256 :  when I am running the script locally the output is showing the correct number of shares bur running from a remote box is giving more count what it is actually

Comment: Yes I understand @AvisekhDas. Please copy and paste the output into your question. We can't help you when you just say "giving me more shares" without showing what it is displaying. Actually showing what type of extra shares e.g. `IPC$` means something that we can help you with.

Comment: @HAL9256: Sorry for my late response . 
here is the correct output
======================
ADMIN$
C$ 
D$ 
E$ 
I$ 
IPC$
L$
M$
N$
Vol10Market10Users$                                              
Vol10MIUsers$                 
Vol11LogisticUsers$                          
Vol13MerchUsers$ 
=============
(count is : 13)


wrong data
=====================
ADMIN$
C$
D$
F$
G$
H$
I$
IPC$
J$
K$
L$
SS_Share$
U$
Vol10
Vol11
Vol13
Vol3
Vol8
Vol9
=======================
count is : 19

Comment: I'm sorry I can't reproduce. From the output, since the output is so wildly different, and the second command is showing more, and different shares, it's not an issue with WMI or PowerShell, but likely because either you are running the command against two different computers, or permissions, e.g. admin permissions. Try running the command against other machines, or from your workstation to try and narrow down the issue.